# AxiosError: maxContentLength size of -1 exceeded

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, axios

I am trying to download some images from a website using axios, but I get this error every time I try. I tried setting the maxContentLength, but it didn't  fix anything.

This is a part of my code

```js
const resp = await axios({
  method: 'GET',
  url: `${host}/data/${chapterHash}/${page}`,
  maxContentLength: 20000,
  responseType: 'arraybuffer'
```

this is the error

```
const err = new AxiosError(                                                                                                                              
^                                                                                                                                      
AxiosError: maxContentLength size of -1 exceeded                                                                                                                 
at IncomingMessage.handlerStreamAborted (C:\Users\alexou\Documents\node-reader\node_modules\axios\dist\node\axios.cjs:2912:23)                               
at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:513:28)                                                                                                                 
at IncomingMessage._destroy (node:_http_incoming:224:10)                                                                                                     
at _destroy (node:internal/streams/destroy:102:25)                                                                                                           
at IncomingMessage.destroy (node:internal/streams/destroy:64:5)                                                                                              
at TLSSocket.socketCloseListener (node:_http_client:441:11)                                                                                                  
at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:525:35)                                                                                                                       
at node:net:757:14                                                                                                                                           
at TCP.done (node:_tls_wrap:584:7) {                                                                                                                       
code: 'ERR_BAD_RESPONSE'
```

Comment: https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/4806

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it about a bug in a 3rd-party library

Answer (score 1):

what I ended up doing was just adding a try{ }catch. The code isn't crashing anymore, but I still get the errors. If you have a better way of handling this, please tell me.